# How to set values to dropdown list in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to set the value of drop down box on my HTML page. I am using angular and I am getting the intended value from REST call.

Other fields like text boxes on my page get the updated value just by saying `ng_mode_textId = myNewVal`.

It does not work for `<select>` tag. How to do it?

Comment: are you using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

Comment: I am new to angular. No I am not. Is this a replacement for select tag? I am using plain select tag

Comment: It's a replacement for the `<option>` tags, check out [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TJLF4pckR5CdkVhycLtF?p=preview) example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify available options in AngularJS for a select component:

```
<select ng-options="pair.id as pair.label for pair in myArray" ng-model="selectedId" />
```

You should set `$scope.myArray` like `[(1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")]`, and read/write `$scope.selectedId` like `1`, `2`, or `3` for this example to work (make these changes in a controller where this select is contained):

```
mymodule.controller(['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [(1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")];
    $scope.selectedId = 1; //lets give him a default selected value
    $scope.someHowYouWillCallThisFunction = function() {
        console.log("The selected id is: " + $scope.selectedId);
    }
}])
```

or for key:value pairs from an object:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myObject" ng-model="selectedId" />
```